# For which min SDK Version of Android should I skip appcompat-v7 Library?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an Android-Studio project having the following in my app build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.majestella.test2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

**What is the smallest version of `minSdkVersion` where I should not use `appcompat-v7` anymore?**

Comment: I prefer using AppCompat even if the framework already supports the features I am using. The library is updated more often than Android versions are released so bug fixes come through faster and apps are less dependent on carriers and their OS updates.

Comment: You shouldn't avoid it: other elements such as the [Android Design Support Library](android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) assume you are using it (i.e., elements like `AppBarLayout` only works with AppCompat `Toolbar`s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AppCompat library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) provides material design widgets & also allows you to use the ToolBar. Most of these features were added in Lollipop, so setting minSdkVersion to 21 would let you use the features without the AppCompat library.

You could also implement material design functionality yourself or just completely avoid it, and set minSdkVersion as low as you want.